# Lucene 4.3: StopwordAnalyzerBase is missing in MultifieldQueryParser

Tags: parsing, lucene, migration

Hi  i have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

all of them at 4.3.

```
MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(Version.LUCENE_43,
                    searchCriteria.getSearchTerms(), searchCriteria
                            .getSearchFields(), new EnglishAnalyzer(
                            Version.LUCENE_43));
```

I get an error saying

```
org.apache.lucene.analysis.StopwordAnalayzerBase is indirectly referenced, however it does not exist.
```

I checked the package and their is `org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.StopWordAnalyzerBase`.

How do I `migrate`? What `dependency` do I need?

My code is l

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got old version of `EnglishAnalyzer` somewhere in the classpath.

`EnglishAnalyzer` in Lucene 4.3 extends `StopWordAnalyzerBase` from the `o.a.l.a.util` package:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.StopwordAnalyzerBase;
...
public final class EnglishAnalyzer extends StopwordAnalyzerBase {
```

In fact, both classes are located in the [same jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.3.0).